# Placeholders in properties file are not replaced when executing maven install goal

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I would like to configure a properties files depending on a profile, either ´dev´ or ´prod´, however the placeholders in the properties file are not replaced when executing the maven install goal.

Here is the pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>abc.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>projectname</name>
<description>Site Description</description>
<url>http://www.myproject.abc</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven-war-plugin.version>2.4</maven-war-plugin.version>
    <tomcat-deploy-path>output</tomcat-deploy-path>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    // various dependencies
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>v${project.artifactId}#${project.version}</finalName>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/profiles/${build.profile.id}/mongo.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${tomcat-deploy-path}</outputDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

</project>
```

The placeholder mongo.properties file:

```
 database.name=${database.name}
 database.port=${database.port}
 database.host=${database.host}
 database.username=${database.username}
 database.password=${database.password}
```

The profiles/dev/mongo.properties file:

```
database.name=mydatabase
database.port=27017
database.host=localhost
database.username=root
database.password=psw1
```

The directory structure is as follows:

```
> myproject
  pom.xml
    > src
       > main
         > java
         > resource
           > profiles
             mongo.properties
             > dev
               mongo.properties
             > prod
               mongo.properties 
         > webapp
       > test
```

I followed the instructions in this blog article: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/creating-profile-specific-configuration-files-with-maven/

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your setup and it worked correctly: the file `WEB-INF/classes/mongo.properties` was correctly replaced.

The problem you are having revolves around the fact that you are outputting the final `war` inside a folder that is **not** under `target`. This is a very bad idea. Currently, the final WAR is generated inside the directory `output`, which corresponds to the property `tomcat-deploy-path` in your POM.

```xml
<tomcat-deploy-path>output</tomcat-deploy-path>
```

The big problem with such a setup is that running `mvn clean` will **not** delete that directory and subsequent builds won't override it, meaning the WAR will never be updated and you will keep an old obsolete WAR. I strongly suggest that you move this property under the Maven build directory, something like

```xml
<tomcat-deploy-path>${project.build.directory}/output</tomcat-deploy-path>
```

so that it is properly cleaned when running `mvn clean`.

As such, to resolve your problem, you should manually delete the folder `output` and rerun `mvn clean install`. It should generate a proper and new WAR.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@..@` instead of `${}`, for example
`database.name=@database.name@`

For more info refer to: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html